# How to get connector shape starting coordinate?

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**
I did this setup to try to get a connector shape starting coordinate by doing some calculations depending on the position of its `BeginConnectedShape` coordinate and `EndConnectedShape` coordinate.

In the image, I created 2 rectangles with identical size (H:50, W:100).
I also have Connector 1 (in red color) and Connector 2 (in black color).
Connector 1 has the same size as the rectangles (H:50, W:100).

I ran below code to get the coordinates in preparation for creating the calculation.

```
Debug.Print "[Rec1]", "T: " & .Shapes(1).Top, "L: " & .Shapes(1).Left, _
  "H: " & .Shapes(1).Height, "W: " & .Shapes(1).Width
Debug.Print "[Rec2]", "T: " & .Shapes(2).Top, "L: " & .Shapes(2).Left, _
  "H: " & .Shapes(2).Height, "W: " & .Shapes(2).Width
Debug.Print "[Con1]", "T: " & .Shapes(3).Top, "L: " & .Shapes(3).Left, _
  "H: " & .Shapes(3).Height, "W: " & .Shapes(3).Width
Debug.Print "[Con2]", "T: " & .Shapes(4).Top, "L: " & .Shapes(4).Left, _
  "H: " & .Shapes(4).Height, "W: " & .Shapes(4).Width
```

I got below results:

> [Rec1]        T: 100        L: 0          H: 50         W: 100
> [Rec2]        T: 50         L: 200        H: 50         W: 100
> [Con1]        T: 75         L: 100        H: 50         W: 100
> [Con2]        T: 25,05433   L: 125,0543   H: 199,9999   W: 49,89134

For Connector 1 the result does make sense. If you draw a box, top is really 75 and left 100.
For Connector 2 however, I didn't get how it got the coordinates. The same can be said in the size.

[image]

I tried to reposition Connector 2 above (see 2nd image) and got a more confusing result.

> [Con2]        T: -25,00016  L: 122,6087   H: 200,8695   W: 50,00008

[image]

**Question**
Has anyone played around with this? Or have some idea how the coordinates are identified?
Better yet, has anyone accomplished the same goal as mine to find the starting coordinate of a connector? Thank you in advance for any lead or advise.

Comment: I think you have to use the ConnectorFormat Property of the connector and perhaps the Adjustments. 
But with the ConnectorFormat you get the BeginConnectedShape etc... see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.connectorformat.type

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve and it's hard to tell what the best solution for this could be.

What I can do is to explain why the top/left/width/height values seems so odd: The secret is *rotation*.

You can rotate any shape (manually or by changing the properte `.rotation` of an shape object using VBA). Rotation doesn't affect the properties for top/left/width/height, those values are always related to the *unrotated* shape.

The following will demonstrate that: The image shows two (green) round edged shapes, a (blue) connector shape and a (red) information shape. I set (using code) the information shape to the coordinates of the connector shape (with a little margin so they don't overlap) and write the coordinates and the rotation values as text into it.

```
Sub showShapeInfo(sh As Shape)
    Const margin = 4
    Dim infoShape As Shape
    Set infoShape = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes("InfoShape")
    
    infoShape.Left = sh.Left - margin
    infoShape.Top = sh.Top - margin
    infoShape.Width = sh.Width + 2 * margin
    infoShape.Height = sh.Height + 2 * margin
    
    Dim txt As String
    txt = sh.Name & vbCrLf _
        & "L: " & Int(sh.Left) & vbCrLf _
        & "T: " & Int(sh.Top) & vbCrLf _
        & "W: " & Int(sh.Width) & vbCrLf _
        & "H: " & Int(sh.Height) & vbCrLf _
        & "R: " & sh.Rotation
    infoShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = txt
End Sub
```

Now when you create the connector and let the code run, it will look like this:

[image]

So the top/left/width/height seems to be unrelated to the connector, but that's because the connector is a shape that is rotated (by 270°).

Now rotating the shape to 0° will reveal the truth (but of course now the connector is no longer connection the shapes)

[image]

As you can see, now the values makes perfectly sense. You can think of placing a shape with rotation by the steps
(1) Place an unrotated shape at the coordinates top/left/width/height
(2) Rotate the shape. Rotation point is the middle point of the shape (at the coordinates `left + (width / 2) , top + (height / 2)`)

---

Note that for a connector shape, the values top/left/width/height are determined by the starting and ending point of the shape, not by the outline. Dragging the yellow handles to change the size of the shape doesn't change those values. If you are interested: Those values are stored in the property `Adjustments`. The following modification of the connector didn't change the values:

[image]